# Laravel Broadcasting issue

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, pusher

Hey Guys I'm trying to broadcast an event through pusher but I'm getting this error

**Timestamp expired: Given timestamp (2018-09-11T22:30:22Z) not within 600s of server time (2018-09-11T23:27:10Z)**

I'm using windows!
how can I fix that?

Comment: You can either solve this by implementing some server time syncing or by performing a restart on homestead.